# IE F12 Hotkey not working

Tags: internet-explorer, hotkeys

My Internet Explorer doesn't show developer tools when I push F12 button.
It works fine when I click on "tools" to find and click "developer tools". It does show the tool.

I googled, but there seems to be no adequate answer for my situation.

Anyone has any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my very old question, it was my SharpKeys key mapping eating my F12 input. Try to see if there is any other app or OS setting mapped to this key binding.

Answer (score 0):

try this [link](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/152554-internet-explorer-f12-developer-tools-enable-disable.html) using the reg file to enable the developers tools